# Why does Pick<T, K> not throw an error when T is passed?

Tags: typescript

I want to create users with a name as parameter from the client and assign `created` on the server. Therefore I use `Pick<User, "name">`. But Typescript does not complain, when I pass a full `User` object to that function:

```js
interface User {
  name: string;
  created: Date;
}

const user: User = {
  name: "Test User",
  created: new Date()
};

const createUser = (user: Pick<User, "name">): User => ({
  name: user.name,
  created: new Date()
});

const newUser1 = createUser(user); // No error
const newUser2 = createUser({
  name: "Another Test User",
  created: new Date() // Error
});
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wave-tewh8

I would expect both cases to throw an error, but the first one does not throw. Why?

Comment: Interesting... had never seen Pick before.. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `User` is a structural subtype of `Pick<User, "name">`. An object of type `Pick<User, "name">` is any object which has a `name` property of type `string`, and a `User` object fits that description, so it is type-safe to pass a `User` where a `Pick<User, "name">` is expected.

The latter case is an error because there is a special rule that [object literals cannot have excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). Although your second example is just as type-safe, it is more likely to be a mistake than the first example, so Typescript warns about it despite silently accepting the same value when it's not passed as an object literal.

If you specifically want this function to not be callable with an argument of type `User`, you could make its parameter type something which `User` is not a subtype of:

```js
interface UninitialisedUser {
    name: string;
    created?: undefined;
}

const createUser = (user: UninitialisedUser): User => ({
    name: user.name,
    created: new Date()
});

const newUser = createUser(user); // error
```

However, note that this doesn't absolutely prevent you from calling the function with a `User` object. You can still write `let temp: { name: string } = user;`, and then `createUser(temp)` won't be a type error. There isn't really a way around that, but at least it's harder to do this by accident.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4CgCQIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3AQlBHJACYUAibEjAvrlyhIsRClQhQwMMDgAbYJnYYseZBuRFSFKjRAMmLXuwD8FAK4h2EGKAjsBQhAHsQVZM1aRVUZAF5kAAoLTCgKSWlZBSUHXwBKCLCAgD5gvEIScmRQ6AA6bQgAGiNvBwoQCAB3ZB5IIPjcfnjGXFd3MBywpKxAjMKKACIAFQgPX0GS-C8TCura3gam1vaPSqrfAM9jHzCQsJbkAHoj5GgoFyhcIA)